# Условия SQL-запроса не выполняются

Tags: sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос

```
SELECT banner_id
FROM b_counts AS counts
  LEFT JOIN b_banner banners ON counts.banner_id = banners.id
  LEFT JOIN b_user users ON counts.user_id = users.id
WHERE banners.is_active = TRUE
      AND (now() BETWEEN banners.start_time AND banners.end_time)
      AND ((SELECT count
            WHERE user_id = 4) <
           banners.max_view OR
           (SELECT count
            WHERE user_id = 4) IS NULL
      )
```

Получаем следующие строки в banner_id: 1, 3, 2, 3, хотя ожидалось только 3.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но для всех записей, у которых user_id не равен 4 ваш странный подзапрос `SELECT count
            WHERE user_id = 4` возвращает NULL. потому что он берет count и user_id из текущей записи, а не еще откуда нибудь

Answer (score 0):

Правильно так

```
SELECT banner_id
FROM b_counts AS counts
  LEFT JOIN b_banner banners ON counts.banner_id = banners.id
  LEFT JOIN b_user users ON counts.user_id = users.id
WHERE banners.is_active = TRUE
      AND (now() BETWEEN banners.start_time AND banners.end_time)
      AND ((counts.count <
           banners.max_view and user_id = 4) OR
           (counts.count IS NULL and user_id = 4)
      )
```

Comment: А почему ***LEFT** JOIN*??? другие не проходили, что ли?